# Access Laravel site outside of network

Tags: laravel, server, apache2, laravel-artisan

I am trying to access my laravel site outside of the network to test functionality, but I am running into some roadblocks I don't quite understand. I have found my computers public IP address, and I have my php artisan serving up my server (for development, won't go into production) yet when I go to the public IP address, it says "this site cannot be reached". I have tried to change my config files (000-default, default-ssl, apache2.conf, etc.) to have the servername be the same as my ip address, but still no luck. I am still a little new at server side things, and could use any help that is offered. Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Comment: why dont you use ngrok? https://ngrok.com/

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much for showing me ngrok!

Comment: awesome glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mac you can install laravel's own tool valet so that you can have access to feature like site sharing just by running `valet share` in your command inside laravel project. Of course installing valet is not necessary what so ever.

There is a great tool called `ngrok` that helps you to share your local server globally. You can use either http or https to share you site.

You can follow the guide here at https://ngrok.com/

Comment: ngrok did it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just you can use Ngrok tools it was allowed to your local project access to the outer network.
YOu can try just download this tool and put in your local project root directory and run it.
You click on the ngrok.exe file then open one terminal and type ngrok command.
for more information, you can check the below video so you can better understand.

https://youtu.be/s8efVe5c1Xg